# Extracting column and row data using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have the following table:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | AA | TEST | A1 |
| 12 | SA | ONLINE | B5 |
| 13 | YA | OFFLINE | N6 |
| 14 | QW | REPORT | LL |
| 15 | LO | DONE | HG |

I would like to print ColumnA and ColumnC such that, if columnA is 11 then it should print TEST. The output should look something like the following:

11 : TEST

12 : ONLINE

13 : OFFLINE

14 : REPORT

15 : DONE

How do I do that?

Comment: you just want to select only columnA and column C?

Comment: Yes, the values corresponding columnA : columnC. The output should be if we select 11 in column a it should give TEST (i.e., 11 : TEST). Similarly for all the cells in columnA